# How does one edit high-octave notes in the score editor?

Tags: garageband

I shifted some notes several octaves up using the Piano Roll view (after finding no way to do it in the Score Editor), but as a result of doing this, it is now impossible to edit the notes from the Score Editor, since they go past the top of the window, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

There is no way to scroll up to bring these notes back into view.

Is there some way to perhaps set the octave represented by the Score view so that the notes appear within the staff instead of above it? I cannot edit this music like this, and it's too difficult to get the timing right using the Piano Roll view.

Comment: I don't use GB myself, but why not see if you can change clef to an octiva (8va) clef - a treble clef sign with an 8 or 15 above it. That would bring the notation down by one or two octaves. Click, or right click, on the clef sign & see what options you get.

Comment: Hmm… this says GB can't do that, but there might be a workaround (which I can't test) https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7997871

Comment: Can you select the notes in the Piano Roll, and then switch to the Score Editor?

Comment: What edit are you trying to perform?

Comment: @Tetsujin I couldn't find any click/key combo that produced any option besides treble clef, bass clef, or both. But I did find that I can scroll by dragging the staff. However, all the notes still appear well above the staff, which isn't very useful. Looks like what I really need is a better piece of software for music editing. Something like GarageBand but without the limitations.

Comment: I found a tool called Avid Sibelius. I'll have to sell my Mac  to be able to afford it, though.

Comment: Garage Band really is very entry-level in terms of functionality, it's certainly not a score editor. Cubase (& probably most equivalent DAWs) have decent scoring capability, though few will be at the level of Sibelius.